# SQL запрос на выборку повторяющихся записей

Tags: sql

Разрабатываю приложение, в котором используется БД. Вот структура некоторых таблиц (для исключения избыточности часть полей и таблиц не указал):

```
create table auto (
  id integer primary key,
  mark varchar(60),
  gosnum varchar(20)
)
create table rules (
  id integer primary key,
  autoid integer,
  unitid integer,
  period integer
)
```

Первая таблица - автомобили. Вторая таблица - правила ТО. На каждый автомобиль может быть несколько правил ТО. Правила строятся по принципу "каждые X ед.изм.", где X - поле period, а ед.изм - unitid. В процессе работы программы значения этих полей могут меняться, что не позволяет сделать словарь правил.

Задача - выбрать из всех правил только повторяющиеся одновременно у всех автомобилей. Правила считаются одинаковыми, если у них совпадают поля period и unitid.

Пример. Пусть есть три автомобиля, и у каждого из них по три правила:

```
A: 1,2,3
B: 2,3,4
C: 3,4,5
```

Здесь цифрами обозначаются правила. Одинаковые цифры - правила с одинаковыми полями period и unitid (поля id при этом у них разные!).

Тогда ответом должно быть правило 3 (точнее его поля period и unitid).

Единственное, до чего я пока что сам дошёл, это реализация алгоритма на C++ с последовательным left join таблицы rules (по каждому автомобилю) к самой себе и отсечением полей со значением null (то есть стандартная конъюнкция). Но, на мой взгляд, это очень нерационально, хотя бы из-за того, что автомобилей будет порядка 10^2.

Comment: у автомобиля не может быть два одинаковых правила? тогда считаем кол-во авто и потом считаем правила.  У которых счетчик равен числу авто - искомые

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если действительно для *всех* автомобилей, то берем общее кол-во автомобилей и сверяем с ним количество данного правила. Если нужно по списку авто - то ограничить выборку правил этим списком и сверять с количеством авто в списке. Написано исходя из того, что в rules не может повторятся одно правило для одного автомобиля более одного раза.

```
select unitid,period
  from rules
 group by unitid,period
having count(1)=(select count(1) from auto)
```

Вообще на rules хорошо бы смотрелся уникальный индекс на поля (unitid,period,autoid), либо вообще отсутствие поля id и включения всех трех полей в primary key. Потому как текущая структура позволяет внести одно правило для авто дважды, а если оно появится - то любые запросы на количество будут нерабочими.

Comment: + плюс еще один уровень, чтоб  получить id правила?

Comment: @splash58 Какой id правила ? Судя по структуре id уникален для всей связки с авто. Значит id из rules будет ровно столько сколько авто

Comment: Да, связь авто-правило действительно есть. Но здесь мне нужно было уловить логику. Добавить в этот запрос выборку по автомобилям уже не так трудно. Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо! Я так и сделаю.

Answer (score 0):

Встроенного быстрого инструмента по удалению повторяющихся записей не существует, так как данная проблема всплывает при некорректной реляционной модели.Вам необходимо пересмотреть структуру БД. Добавьте еще одну таблицу auto_TO_rules_link которая будет содержать поля [auto_id,rule_id] и добавьте уникальные (составные) ключи по 3 полям в правилах ТО. Так вы сможете избежать подобных проблем.